# web2py - How to programmatically register users?

Tags: web2py

I would like to register users programmatically, so I can test my application with multiple users.

The way I thought of doing this was:

```
if db( db.auth_user ).count() == 0:
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for letter in alphabet:
        db.auth_user.validate_and_insert( first_name=letter , last_name=letter , email='%s@%s.com'%(letter , letter) , username=letter , password='qwer' )
```

This however doesn't set the other tables about group membership etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
from gluon.storage import Storage
onaccept = auth.settings.register_onaccept.pop() # Disable registration callback.
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for letter in alphabet:
    user = auth.register_bare(first_name=letter, last_name=letter,
                              email='%s@%s.com' % (letter, letter),
                              username=letter, password='qwer')
    user and onaccept(Storage(vars=user))
auth.settings.register_onaccept = [onaccept] # Restore registration callback.
```

The above temporarily disables the `register_onaccept` callback, as a bug in `register_bare` prevents it from working properly. Instead, it is called manually after the registration, passing in the `user` object (which is the full user record, including the `id` field).

Comment: This almost worked. I have an `auth.settings.register_onaccept` function which takes `form` as a variable and uses `form.vars.id`. But in this case `form.vars` isn't defined. Any hints?

Comment: I would say this is a bug in `auth.register_bare` -- it passes a dictionary of the user fields to `register_onaccept`, but it does not include the `id` (and there is no `.vars` attribute). I would say either re-write the callback to deal with the alternative input (and if you need the id, get it by doing a lookup based on the email), or disable the callback and instead call it manually, passing it the returned user object (the answer has been updated with this latter approach).

Comment: An [issue](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/1192) has been submitted to fix the bug. You can use the above workaround for now.

Comment: thank you, I ended up doing a db lookup on the username inside the onaccept function in case the form.user isn't defined. It seems that what is passed in `form` is a Storage object with keys `first_name`, `last_name` etc

Comment: meant `form.vars` not `form.user`

Answer (score 1):

You can look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/8Y8ustcypGw) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201300/how-can-i-create-new-auth-user-and-auth-group-on-web2py-running-on-google-app-en), basicly for add a user and assign a group you can:

```
new_user_id = db.auth_user.insert(first_name="Admin",
                                  last_name="Username",
                                  email="mye...@address.com",
                                  password=db.auth_user.password.requires[0]('mypassword')[0])
auth.add_membership('admin', db.auth_user(new_user_id) )
```